# Maven dependency for kendo taglib jar

Tags: java, jsp, maven, kendo-ui

I am trying to revamp an existing jsp application with kendo ui. Its a maven application with studs framework.
 Right now I am adding the kendo-taglib-2012.3.1322 jar externally into my build path. Bur it is giving an error saying taglib not found. I cannot see this jar in my deployed .ear file

I want to add the dependency for this jar in my pom.xml.
Can anyone please give the maven dependency foe this jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add \wrappers\jsp\kendo-taglib\kendo-taglib-[version].jar to project's /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder.